# array_combine() from PHP equivalent in Python?

Tags: php, python, arrays, list, dictionary

I'm trying to do something like:

```
keys = [2,3,10]  # or even with assosiative keys like "orange", "apple", ..
vals = [7,9,11]
dict = array_combine(keys,vals)
```

Any way to implent that example as using array_combine() bult-in funcion of PHP5 ?

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php

Comment: What is the expected output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
dict(zip(keys, vals))
```

Seems to be what you want.

Demo:

```
>>> keys = [2,3,10]
>>> vals = [7,9,11]
>>> dict(zip(keys, vals))
{2: 7, 3: 9, 10: 11}
```

[`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/functions.html#zip) puts elements at corresponding indices within the two lists into tuples. We can then put those pairs together into a new structure with the [`dict`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/stdtypes.html#dict) constructor.